# SQL Server 2008 r2 instance/network connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I had installed SQL server 2008 r2 on my computer and created a database. I accidentally moved the SQL server folder from my local drive, where it was installed, to E Drive. Now when i copy it again to program files in my C drive and try to connect it, it cannot connect. It gives error stating "the network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The SQL server was not found or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections."

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0d0aac32-1241-4fa0-bd69-691b8fea21cf/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and check properties to verify that `Startup Parameters` have correct path to `MASTER` database. Here is link on moving master http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx#master

Comment: I cannot open SQL server configuration manager. It says mmc could not create snap-in.

Comment: In that case you should re-install SQL Server with repair function.